# Run batch file with custom drive mappings

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, command-line, batch-file

I want to create a "mini virtual environment" to run a program.  The only difference between my normal environment and the virtual one would be the drive mappings.

- I have an `X:` drive mapped to `\\some\network\location`
- I have a program `myapp.exe` that expects the `X:` drive to be mapped to `C:\local\path`
- I need to keep my `X:` drive mapped to `\\some\network\location` throughout the process

I would like to be able to run the following batch file and not have it affect the current environment:

```
subst X: C:\local\path
myapp.exe
```

Comment: One way to accomplish this is to use the `runas` command to execute the batch file.  The downside to this approach is that you must supply the user password every time, even if you `runas` the current user.

Answer (score 0):

If the path the application checks does not yet exist, you can temporarily make a symbolic link. The application will find the files it needs in the directory it expects, while the file system redirects operations almost transparently to the actual path. Use with caution; (un)expected bad stuff may happen if, for example, `C:\local\path\` already exists.

By default, Windows only grants users in the Administrators group privileges to create symbolic links. Therefore, the following script would have to be run with elevation, or (Windows 7) the permissions would have to be set through the security policy (`secpol.msc` or Control Panel, Administrative Tools, Local Security Policy) in the section Local Policies, User Rights Assignment.

```
mklink /D C:\local\path X:\
myapp.exe
rmdir C:\local\path
```

Comment: I prefer SUBST.exe to this method since, if you ever had to delete the symbolic link then it would SEEM to be very precarious.  Using the "subst /d X:" command is much safer and less scary than using "rm -r X:\" .   I know MKLINK is a symbolic link but i would still want to be careful "just in case" it was a hard link.

Comment: Interesting approach, but several of the files I need on the local `X:` drive will also exist in the network `X:` drive.  I am trying to set up automated testing using test data on my local `X:` drive.  So the potential overlap of files is not only possible but it's kind of the whole point.  That approach definitely has merit for other use cases, though.